# How to return more features from GetFeatureInfo?

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I configured WFS service with "Maximum number of features for preview" to 50 but when i try to get features my request returns only one value, for example

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":"unknown","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"GRAY_INDEX":-9999}}],"crs":null}
```

and with &feature_count parameter geoserver accepts only 50 as value but also adding this the ouput is the same the above. Instead I want an output as:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":"unknown","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"GRAY_INDEX":-9999}}, {"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"GRAY_INDEX":4}}],"crs":null}
```

**EDIT1:**

In my Geoserver I have multiple time spaced rasters for each layer. When I try the GetFeatureInfo request above I specify also a time range as &time=[from]/[to]. Because the bounding box of these rasters are overlapped, I want that the WMS request returns a list of pixel features when I click on the overlapped area.

**EDIT2:**

The request is:

```
geoserver/ows?service=wms&request=GetFeatureInfo&info_format=application/json&feature_count=50&exceptions=application/json&bbox=-4.226473,39.039063,16.516447,79.980469&layers=id210s013016r000-europe&query_layers=id210s013016r000-europe&width=381&height=752&crs=EPSG:4258&time=2016-03-03T23:00:00.000Z/2016-03-04T20:00:00.000Z&i=338&j=134
```

Comment: You are mixing WFS service and GetFeatureInfo request which belongs to WMS. But based on the return value you are making GetFeatureInfo for a raster layer. You would like to get info from many pixels, or? I believe that it is not supported.

Comment: I'm assuming you have turned the time dimension on for the raster? Can you add your actual request to the question

Comment: @iant How can check If time dimension is on?

Comment: look at the layer's entry in the getCapabilities document

Comment: @iant yes Time is enabled in the Dimensions tab

Answer (score 1):

You are making a `GetFeatureInfo` request to a WMS service, the WMS is required by the standard to return information about the point you have clicked on. If there is more than one feature at the point then it may return information about all the features (up to `featureCount`) that are there.

You seem to be asking for information about a raster so the request returns the value of the pixel that is at the point you have clicked on. Since you seem not to have many layers there you will only get back one pixel's value regardless of how high you set `featureCount`.

If you are trying to fetch an area of the raster then you probably want to look at using a [Web Coverage Service (WCS)](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wcs/index.html) request.

Comment: In theory GetFeatureInfo with vendor parameter "buffer" could fetch an area http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#wms-vendor-parameters.

Comment: @user30184 - sort of but it is ugly and difficult to use that way

Comment: I have multiple time spaced raster for one layer. When I click I can see that the pixel is inside two different rasters and so I want that WMS returns both pixels.

Comment: @MarcoCiaramella - you will need to edit your question with more detail about your setup and the requests you are making. Do you have time set in the request?

Comment: @iant yes I have time set in the request in the form of from_time/to_time.

Comment: @iant I edited my question with more info.