# GeoServer WMS GetFeatureInfo only returning one Feature?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, getfeatureinfo

This is how I get feature info from a **group layer** when clicking on the map (using WMS `GetFeatureInfo`):

```js
let view = this.map.getView()
let viewResolution = view.getResolution();
var source = this.groupLayer.getSource();

var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
  this.map.getEventCoordinate(event), 
  viewResolution, 
  view.getProjection(), 
  {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'}
);

this.expedientesService.getExpsClick(url).subscribe(exps => {
  console.log(exps)
})
```

**The problem:** This request is returning only one feature even if there are more than one on that clicked point.

The URL generated by `getGetFeatureInfoUrl` has the following format:

```
http://foo?
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.3.0&
REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&
FORMAT=image%2Fpng&
TRANSPARENT=true&
QUERY_LAYERS=groupLayer&
LAYERS=groupLayer&
INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&
I=50&
J=50&
CRS=EPSG%3Axyz&
STYLES=&
WIDTH=101&
HEIGHT=101&
BBOX=570384.8749920629%2C4722144.92875535%2C570386.7576818952%2C4722146.811445182
```

(I think I and J are always 50, don't know why)

> [As seen here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/189411/138448) If there is more than one feature at the point then
>   it may return information about all the features (up to
>   `featureCount`) that are there.

Any idea of what is wrong here?

I have an auxiliary layer containing all the features, and when making a WFS `GetFeature` request, multiple features are returned.

Comment: I do not see featurecount in the request.

Comment: You are right! I did just found that by default the number of features returned is 1. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was at the generation of the `GetFeatureInfo` URL. I didn't set the `Feature_Count` parameter, which sets the maximum number of features that can be returned. [As seen here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html) it is set to 1 by default.

I solved this problem adding the `feature_count` field as following:

```
var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
  this.map.getEventCoordinate(evt), 
  viewResolution, 
  view.getProjection(), 
  {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
    'FEATURE_COUNT': '1000'}
);
```

Special thanks to *@user30184* for his comment.